# iPhone Provisioning Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I been writing my App using Xcode 3.2 and I recently upgraded to Xcode 4.2 and set it for developing for iOS 3.2 or newer. I’m now trying to get my App to run on my iPhone 3G which is running iOS 4.2.1. (Current version.) I successfully run my App on iPhone 4.3 simulators & 5.0 simulators. But, when I try to run on my iPhone, I get the following error:

```
valid signing identity not found.
```

I named my App Id as `com.myname.App`

I‘ve gone through several tutorials on getting this provisioned, so I’ve become accustomed to the steps.  I’ve tried changing the Bundle Identifier, using the iPhone Provisioning Portal Login and changing the Name on the Key in the Key Chain.

I’ve deleted all Certificates and Provisioning and started from scratch several times.

When I joined the Apple Developer program last week, I used my “short” name, but my credit card had my “long” name on it. Now, my Development Certificate shows my “short” name, but my Distribution Certificate shows my “long” name. Does that matter?

When I check my Key Chain Access, it shows both keys in Login.

I guess my question mostly is, what names have to be exactly the same ie: App Id, Keys, Development Certificate, Bundle Identifier and is it case sensitive?

What am I overlooking?

Do I have a SDK vs iOS conflict of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest checking the profiles attached in the target section . Sometimes when you modify the project settings , those don't get reflected in the target settings . So I doubt the target settings are still using the older profile ( which may be of the exactly same name like the newer one which you want to use ) . If it is so , you can re-select the provisioning profile there in the target .. Just clean and re-run  the project .

Answer (score 0):

As you use latest ios in xcode and your iPhone have a 4.2 ios version, just change the target deployment version relate to your iPhone IOS version in xcode. Check your bundle identifire and code signing identity is correct? also check in developer site that your iPhone UDID is added.